# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring

I want to make a POST request to a web service using Spring RestTemplate.

This is my method:

```
public void sendDataToServer(DataEvent dataEvent){

        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
        rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        String uri = "post URL"; //url is correct but I am hiding it here.

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity(dataEvent,headers);

        rt.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
    }
```

I am getting an exception saying:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
```

**When I use Postman to make the request directly to that URL without going through my web service it works fine and requires no authorization at all.**

[image: Authorization screenshot]

[image: Headers tab]

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Check postman, if it's sending the `Authorization` header in the request.

Comment: @11thdimension Just added a screenshot. I think it isn't doing that.

Comment: It's a screenshot of `Body` tab, post one for `Headers` tab

Comment: @11thdimension That was a screenshot of Authorization tab. I uploaded one of headers tab too.

Comment: @11thdimension Added another one :)

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the response, yes this request does not have any Authorization header. Just to make sure add an Authorization header with random value, so that if browser has one saved previously it will be overwrrtten

Comment: Added one, still the same thinfg. Removed it and tried again, still the same thing.

Comment: Then it means that it doesn't have any Authorization, now the next step would be to check if your Java request is exactly same as the Postman one.

Comment: Wait, how did I not see this, your post man is also return 401 :) , nothing is wrong here Java and Postman are seeing the same things.

Comment: So I have a web service running on my local Tomcat. This web service calls another web service and sends a post request. This scenario gives me a 401.
When I sent a post request directly to that URL from postman (without going through my local tomcat) it works fine. This is the issue I am trying to resolve. @11thdimension

Comment: Is directly calling `sendDataToServer` in main working ?